# URLs extraction from specific block

Tags: python

This script extracts all urls from a specific HTML div block (with BeautifulSoup 4) :

```
raw_data = dl("http://somewhere")
links = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_data)
data = str(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : "results"}))
for link in BeautifulSoup(data, parse_only = SoupStrainer('a')):
    links.append(urllib.parse.unquote_plus(link['href']))
return links
```

Is there a more efficient and clean way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can use [List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to make it more efficient

```
raw_data = dl("http://somewhere")
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_data)
data = str(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : "results"}))
return  [ urllib.parse.unquote_plus(link['href']) for link in BeautifulSoup(data, parse_only = SoupStrainer('a'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **lmxl.html** + **xpath**

Let's say, the html you get from "url" is:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="foo">
                <a href="#foo1">foo1</a>
                <a href="#foo2">foo2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="results">
                <a href="#res1">res1</a>
                <a href="#res2">res2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="bar">
                <a href="#bar1">bar1</a>
                <a href="#bar2">bar2</a>
            </div>
            <div id="abc">
                <a href="#abc">abc</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#nothing">nothing</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#xyz">xyz</a>
        </body>
   </html>
```

Here is how I would do:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml.html import parse

if __name__ == '__main__':

    tree = parse(url)
    hrefs = tree.xpath("//div[@class='results']/a/@href")

    print hrefs
```

Output:

```
['#res1', '#res2']
```